# Python easy_install gives [errno13]

Tags: python, ssh, easy-install

I'm tring to install [Hookbox](http://hookbox.org/) but without success, when I call `easy_install` or

```
python setup.py install
```

it gives me `[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/test-easy-install-68779.write-test'`

When I try to grant write permissions to this derectory it gives

```
chmod: /usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/: Operation not permitted
```

is there any way to solve this prob or install hookbox without easy_install?

Comment: belongs to superuser.com

Comment: If you can't use sudo, you can't install things.  You have a problem that we cannot solve.  Find your sysadmin and either get sudo privs or get another job.

Answer (score 8):

You should have used appropriate privilege to install

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

Another option is to use virtualenv to create a isolated environment where you could install

- http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv

Another way is too install some where, where you have permission.

```
python setup.py install --home=<dir>
```

see also the alternate unix installation with option prefix

```
python setup.py install --prefix=/usr/local
```

See the details of these options in the docs: http://docs.python.org/install/

If you ask my preference it would be virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper, pip and yolk to manage external modules. google for them